# I purchased the iOS app System Status and not sure how to use it

Tags: iphone

I purchased [System Status (an activity monitor app)](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/system-status-activity-monitor/id401457165?mt=8) for my iPhone as I read here in the forum it can stop the activity ball from rotating without rebooting the iPhone. Can someone that uses this app please tell me how to do this as I missed something somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: The app in the iTunes store is called System Status. The problem I had was the little activity circle next to wifi was spinning for hours. I fixed it by restarting. But the app before 10.11 allowed you to stop this without restart. All good now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the app no longer allows you to stop an app or a activity as Apple stopped this function by sandboxing the apps.